# Increment by 1 for ttk scale

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

My problem is thatI Have a scale and a spinbox which change each other's values. OFr example if both go from 1 to 100, if I set the scale to 50, the spinbox will also change and vice versa. now I've got this to work pretty well except for one minor problem. I can't get the ttk scale to go up by whole numbers. Everytimer I change the scale, I get a ton of decimals behind my number. Here is my code:

```
def create_widgets(self):
"""my widgets"""
    spinval = IntVar()

    self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                                   length = 200,
                                   from_ = 1, to = 100,
                                   variable = spinval)
    self.scale.grid(row = 3,column = 1,sticky = W)


    self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, from_ = 1, to = 100,
                                   textvariable = spinval,
                                   command = self.update,
                                   width = 10)
    self.spinbox.grid(row = 3,column =3,sticky = W)

def update(self, nothing):
    """Updates the scale and spinbox"""
    self.scale.set(self.spinbox.get())
```

Now my question is: is it somehow possible to make it increment by whole numbers or change the graphic of the normal Tkinter scale so it looks better. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def create_widgets(self):
    """my widgets"""
    spinval = IntVar()

    self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                length=200,
                                from_=1, to=100,
                                variable=spinval,
                                command=self.accept_whole_number_only)
    self.scale.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)


    self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, from_=1, to=100,
                                textvariable=spinval,
                                command=self.update,
                                width=10)
    self.spinbox.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky=W)

def accept_whole_number_only(self, e=None):
    value = self.scale.get()
    if int(value) != value:
        self.scale.set(round(value))

def update(self, e=None):
    """Updates the scale and spinbox"""
    self.scale.set(self.spinbox.get())
```